# Automating telnet process with batch file

Tags: batch-file, telnet

Greetings stack community, I'm looking for a way to automate when I need to telnet.

This is the flow that I go through when I telnet:

-I open cmd and I telnet:
Z:>telnet 10.01.02.12 300

-When I telnet to every IP the command propmt will ask for my user, once I input my user I need to press enter.

*cmd screen clears*

USER: *I type my user*

-Then cmd will ask for my password, then I enter the password and press enter.

PASSWORD: *I type my password*

-Once the password has been accepted, I'm required to enter 1 and press enter.

User & Password have been accepted, please enter 1:

*I enter 1*

Connection has been established.

Z:\

So I'm creating a .bat file which I can use to automate this, is there a way that I can pass the arguments of username, password, and the input of 1. ?

These is what I have so far in the .bat

```
@ECHO-OFF
ECHO Performing telnets
ECHO connecting to 10.01.02.12
telnet 10.01.02.12 300
ECHO connecting to 10.02.06.34
telnet 10.02.06.34 300
ECHO You have telnet to above IPs successfully.
PAUSE
```

Comment: Is this the Telnet feature in Windows 10, or something you downloaded?  The Windows 10 version accepts `/?` as a parameter.  Looks like `-l user` will work, but I don't see anything for password.  You can join multiple ECHOs by surrounding them in parentheses and pipe the output as input to a command, but, as far as I know, there isn't anyway to later switch the input source for the command.  So full automation is probably possible, but automating only the first few steps is more difficult and would probably require something AutoIt, QuickMacros, or similar.

Comment: Thank you, yes this looks like it wont be possible without some extended amount of coding.

Answer (score 0):

How about a little bit of a compromise?  Place the following lines at the top of your script (replacing UserName and Password with your info) and when you switch to each telnet window you should be able to do a CTRL+V to paste the answers to each question.

```
@ECHO OFF
(
    ECHO:UserName
    ECHO;Password
    ECHO;1
)|clip
```